# Firefox automatic redirect when user visits specific site

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I am writing a firefox extension that when a user visits the homepage of a predefined site they will automatically be redirected to different page on that same site. The problem is that it creates a redirect loop because it redirects every page on particular site not just the homepage. I want to just redirect the user when they visit the homepage, not every time they visit any page on that same site.

```
var myExt_urlBarListener = {
QueryInterface: function(aIID)
{
if (aIID.equals(Components.interfaces.nsIWebProgressListener) ||
       aIID.equals(Components.interfaces.nsISupportsWeakReference) ||
       aIID.equals(Components.interfaces.nsISupports))
     return this;
   throw Components.results.NS_NOINTERFACE;
  },

  onLocationChange: function(aProgress, aRequest, aURI)
  {
    myExtension.processNewURL(aURI);
  },

  onStateChange: function(a, b, c, d) {},
  onProgressChange: function(a, b, c, d, e, f) {},
  onStatusChange: function(a, b, c, d) {},
  onSecurityChange: function(a, b, c) {}
};

var myExtension = {
  oldURL: null,

  init: function() {
    // Listen for webpage loads
    gBrowser.addProgressListener(myExt_urlBarListener,
    Components.interfaces.nsIWebProgress.NOTIFY_LOCATION);
  },

  uninit: function() {
    gBrowser.removeProgressListener(myExt_urlBarListener);
  },

  processNewURL: function(aURI) {
    if (aURI.spec == this.oldURL)
      return;

    // now we know the url is new...
    //alert(aURI.spec);
    if(aURI.spec.search("www.examplesite.com") > -1){ 
        gBrowser.contentDocument.location.href = "http://www.examplesite.com/page1";
    }
    this.oldURL = aURI.spec;
  }
};

window.addEventListener("load", function() {myExtension.init()}, false);
window.addEventListener("unload", function() {myExtension.uninit()}, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Surely this is just a matter of changing `if(aURI.spec.search("www.examplesite.com") > -1){` so that you're comparing for the actual specific URL...?

Comment: How would I go about doing that?